# Error while compiling cocos2d-x v3 IOS project,on integrating AdMob (IOS) framework

Tags: c++, ios, admob, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

When i compile my cocos2d-x V3 project in Xcode, it runs fine but on including AdMob framework, it displays following linker error.

I already have included "-ObjC" in "Other linker" section under Build Settings.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
>         -[GADVideoPlayer setAudioMixVolume:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADVideoPlayer.o)
>     "_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds", referenced from:
>         -[GADVideoPlayer seekToTime:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADVideoPlayer.o)
>     "_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
>         -[GADVideoPlayer notifyVideoPlayerWithTime:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADVideoPlayer.o)
>         -[GADVideoPlayer notifyVideoReadyToPlay] in GoogleMobileAds(GADVideoPlayer.o)
>     "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
>         -[GADVideoPlayer observePlayer] in GoogleMobileAds(GADVideoPlayer.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventEditViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADOpener.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADOpener.o)
>     "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
>         l001 in GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureUtil.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADDevice.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADOpener.o)
>     "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
>         ___35-[GADNetwork enableNetworkChecking]_block_invoke in GoogleMobileAds(GADNetwork.o)
>     "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
>         l001 in GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureUtil.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventStore", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADSlot+MRAID.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADOpener.o)
>     "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue", referenced from:
>         ___35-[GADNetwork enableNetworkChecking]_block_invoke in GoogleMobileAds(GADNetwork.o)
>         ___36-[GADNetwork disableNetworkChecking]_block_invoke in GoogleMobileAds(GADNetwork.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEvent", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADOpener.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADDevice.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureIdUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADMAdURLAdapter.o)
>     "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
>         ___35-[GADNetwork enableNetworkChecking]_block_invoke in GoogleMobileAds(GADNetwork.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADDevice.o)
>     "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
>         ___48-[GADDevice enableRadioAccessTechnologyChecking]_block_invoke_2 in GoogleMobileAds(GADDevice.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

Ahh! finally solved it by adding the following frameworks in my project, in **Link Binary With Libraries** section under **Build Phases** in Xcode.

- AdSupport
- AudioToolbox
- AVFoundation
- CoreGraphics
- CoreMedia
- CoreTelephony
- EventKit
- EventKitUI
- MessageUI
- StoreKit
- SystemConfiguration